# difference between these 2 hosting packages?

Tags: hosting, web-hosting, host

This hosting provider has 2 packages at the same price, 1 is called webhosting and the other is called wordpress, they cost both $4.

The only difference between those two is that the webhosting package provides 1000gb of network traffic and wordpress only 100. The webhosting does have mysql & PHP.

Why would you buy the the wordpress package if the webhosting package provides more network traffic?

Answer (score 0):

With shared hosting packages (WordPress or Conventional web hosting), bandwidth isn't important thing to be considered. Most of the shared packages never going to utilize more than 20 GB transfer. Knowing this fact, web hosts add more 0s to their offer to make it look more exciting. The fact is, you'll never going to use that much amount of bandwidth and you aren't getting any extra value.

I believe WordPress packages must have some additional features like, SSD storage, built in CDN, Caching Mechanisms, more RAM, CPU, Inodes, entry processes, etc. compared to ordinary web hosting. Better you ask your web hosting provider.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking to compare different web hosting packages head over to [Hosting Recipe](http://www.hostingrecipe.com) which will help you.